# Unable to emit events when wrapping a Vue 3 component into a custom element

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, web-component, emit, custom-events

When using the following code to wrap a Vue 3 component into a custom element, I noticed that Vue events were not received by the caller.

```
import { createApp, defineCustomElement, getCurrentInstance, h } from "vue"

export const defineVueCustomElement = (component: any, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
  defineCustomElement({
    styles: component.styles,
    props: component.props,
    emits: component.emits,
    setup(props, { emit }) {
      const app = createApp();
      plugins.forEach((plugin) => {
        app.use(plugin);
      });
      const inst = getCurrentInstance();
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context);
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides);
      return () =>
        h(component, {
          ...props,
        });
    },
  })
```

But when I wrote a simpler code, Vue events can be received by the client correctly. The drawback of the code is that it doesn't support Vue plugins:

```
import { defineCustomElement } from "vue"

export const defineVueCustomElement = (component: any) => {
  defineCustomElement(component)
}
```

I am wondering why the first piece of code was not working correctly? How should I correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After digging HOURS into this, I managed to get it to work.
Here's your code updated:

```
export const defineVueCustomElement = (component: any, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
  defineCustomElement({
    styles: component.styles,
    props: component.props,
    emits: component.emits,
    setup(props, { emit }) {
      const app = createApp();
      plugins.forEach((plugin) => {
        app.use(plugin);
      });
      const inst = getCurrentInstance();
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context);
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides);

      const events = Object.fromEntries(
        (component.emits || []).map((event: string) => {
          return [
            `on${ event[0].toUpperCase() }${ event.slice(1) }`,
            (payload: unknown) => emit(event, payload)
          ];
        })
      );

      return () =>
        h(component, {
          ...props,
          ...events
        });
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @herobrine I managed to get it to work with components defined as async (since we don't want to "load" all web components at once, instead load them on demand).
So given

```
window.customElements.define(
        `org-custom-element`,
        defineCustomElement({
            // lazy loaded component (chunk)
            rootComponent: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./MyComponent.ce.vue')),
            globalStyles: [globalStyles],
            plugins: {
                install(app: App) {
                    app.use(store);
                    app.use(i18n);
                },
            },
        })
    );
```

we defined `defineCustomElement` as

```
const extractEventNamesFromEmits = (
    emits
) => {
    if (Array.isArray(emits)) {
        return emits;
   }

    if (typeof emits === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(emits);
    }

    return [];
};

export const defineCustomElement = ({
  rootComponent,
  plugins,
  globalStyles = []
}) =>
  vueDefineCustomElement({
props: rootComponent.props,
styles: globalStyles,
setup(props, ctx) {
  const app = createApp()
  app.component("org-cpm-root", rootComponent)
  app.use(plugins)

  const inst = getCurrentInstance()

  Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
  Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)

  rootComponent.setup?.(props, ctx)
  // important
  const isAsyncComponent = rootComponent.name === "AsyncComponentWrapper"
  const onVnodeMounted = isAsyncComponent
    ? vnode => {
        asyncVnode.value = vnode
      }
    : undefined

  const asyncVnode = ref(null)
  const events = computed(() => {
    const asyncComponentEmits =
      isAsyncComponent &&
      typeof asyncVnode.value?.type === "object" &&
      "emits" in asyncVnode.value.type
        ? asyncVnode.value.type.emits
        : null

    return Object.fromEntries(
      (
        extractEventNamesFromEmits(
          asyncComponentEmits ?? rootComponent.emits
        ) ?? []
      ).map(eventName => {
        return [
          `on${eventName[0].toUpperCase()}${eventName.slice(1)}`,
          payload => ctx.emit(eventName, payload)
        ]
      })
    )
  })

  return () =>
    h(rootComponent, {
      ...props,
      ...events.value,
      onVnodeMounted
    })
}
})
```

Basically if we detect that component name is `AsyncComponentWrapper` then we will listen on underlying VNode being mounted. When it has mounted we will re-render component with events extracted from this VNode `emits` option. It may not work in all cases, but it works in our case and allows the event to be properly "catched" and dispatched as Custom DOM events.